# sql join with two tables with avg

Tags: sql, join, average

i have two tables
employee :

employee_number  employee_name  salary  divison_id

division :

division_id  division_name

How to Show employee number, employee name, division_name and average salary of all employees in each division.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is a pretty basic SQL query.

Comment: Two tables involved: JOIN.

Comment: average salary: GROUP BY

Comment: [mcve] - to make it possible to assist you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT employee.employee_number, employee.employee_name, division.division_name, 
    AVG(salary) AS AvgSalary
FROM employee
JOIN division ON division.division_id = employee.division_id
GROUP BY employee_number, employee_name, division_name
```

However, I'm not certain this will achieve your desired result.

To show the "average salary of all employees in each division", you'd do something such as:

```
SELECT division.division_name AS Division, AVG(salary) AS AvgSalary FROM division
JOIN employee ON employee.division_id = division.division_id
GROUP BY division_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT employee_number, employee_name, division_name, AVG(amount)
FROM employee
JOIN division ON division.division_id=employee.division_id
GROUP BY division_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your databse supports analytical function then you can use it as follows:

```
SELECT e.employee_number, e.employee_name, d.division_name, 
       AVG(salary) over (partition by d.division_id) as avg_sal_div
  FROM employee e
  JOIN division d ON d.division_id=e.division_id;
```